# What can we call the two parts of a dichotomy?

Tags: single-word-requests

If someone has set up a dichotomy (an "either a, or b" exclusive disjunction kind of argument), how can we then refer back to the two parts being contrasted, such that one could form a sentence like, "if one grants the latter "dichotom", then xyz).  "Dichotom," however does not appear to be a word.  So what actual word would be a good substitute?

Answer (score 3):

*Alternative* is a good word for that.

Comment: +1 I agree with this one.

Answer (score 1):

As the question implies, there are two kinds of disjunction, the **inclusive**, in which, of the two statements (or *terms*), A and B, one or the other or both may be true.  For example,

> You can have sugar or milk in your tea.

This relationship is expressed using a symbol representing the Latin word *vel*, where "A vel B" means A or B or both A and B.  The symbol used is the letter 'v' (the first letter of the Latin inclusive disjunction, *vel*.

In logic, we can say that (A v B) implies both (not-A implies B) and (not-B implies A).  That is, if A is false, B is true and if B is false A is true.  A and B cannot both be false but they
can both be true.

We can speak of A and B as the *terms* of the disjunction.

The **exclusive** disjunction, as is said in the question, represents alternatives/a dichotomy.  One of the terms must be true, but not both.   In logic it is expressed by the Latin word *aut*, a word that conveys exclusive disjunction. The symbol used is a an upside down 'v', to suggest the 'A' for *Aut* without the crossbar (used also by a car manufacturer of a car model with and 'A' in its name). My lack of keyboard skill leaves me with '^', which I use with apology.

In logic, A ^ B is a way to say that the truth of the first term (A) implies that the second term (B) is false and vice versa.  It is logically equivalent to

> A -> -B, (or "A implies not-B"), which, *mutatis mutandis* implies B -> -A, or "B implies not-A". One or the other *term* **but not both** is true.

Historically, the German Frege in the late 19th century and finally Bertrand Russell in the early 20th century established the relatedness between logic and mathematics.  So the word *term* came into use to express what stood one side or the other of a logical relationship.  Logic, it turned out worked a bit like algebraic equations.

Comment: So, term could be the word I'm looking for, then?  The logic lesson was refreshing, so thank you.  Logic was one of my favorite courses I took in college.

Comment: @Jonathan Muse  Yes.   For example, in the Cambridge English Dictionary includes:  "[ C ]   MATHEMATICS   specialized
a number or symbol used in a mathematical series or calculation:
We then use the same rule to compute the terms of the equation.
The terms of a geometric series form a geometric progression, meaning that the ratio of successive terms in the series is constant."

Answer (score 1):

A dichotomy produces parts, so I think you’ve answered your own question.

> **dichotomy**, *n.*
> **1. a.** Division into two sharply defined or contrasting parts; (*Logic*) division into two mutually exclusive categories or genera;
> binary classification. Also: an instance of such division.
> <sub>Source: [Oxford English Dictionary](https://oed.com) (login
> required)</sub>

If you can give the parts a more specific label, go for it. Your example sentence, with its use of *grants* (concedes), suggests that your two parts are arguments:

> *If one grants the latter argument, then xyz.*

(Again, I think you’ve answered your own question.)

> *If one understands the latter possibility, then xyz.*
>
> *If one chooses the latter alternative, then xyz.*

And so on.

Answer (score 1):

The words ***dilemma*** and ***dichotomy*** are very closely related (see Wikipedia: [***false dilemma**, also referred to as **false dichotomy***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_dilemma)). The difference is the former more strongly alludes to the need to *make a choice*, where the latter stresses the fact of two things being *mutually incompatible*.

So [here's a chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%20*%20of%20a%20dilemma&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) showing that when referring to the two "components" that constitute a ***dilemma***, there's one particularly well-established term...

[image]

TL;DR: We don't say *the horns of a dichotomy*, but we *do* say ***the horns of a dilemma***.

Comment: Dilemma means two (competing) truths, (lemmas are proofs). Dichotomy means two parts (same root as _microtome_, meaning 'cut'); the parts don't have to be opposite or competing, they just have to be separate.

Comment: oic - obvious when you point it out. Well, the *dilemma* etymology was immediately recognizable to me 'cos I knew *lemma*, but I didn't get the *-tome = 'cut'* business until it dawned on me *hysterectomy* has "the same" roots. So if I'd learned *vas deferens* first, I wouldn't have needed to "learn" *vasectomy* at all, 'cos I could have worked it out whenever I needed to. I'm sure there are a whole bunch of other *-ectomies* I already know without needing to remember them. English is surely "complicated", but it's encouraging to see bits of it reflect regular patterns well worth knowing.

Answer (score 0):

Option (if the dichotomy is a choice), case, possibility, eventuality.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by citing some sources showing example usages, definitions etc.  As it stands it has been flagged as being of low quality.